# Execute the formula Only if we feed in to the cell - No "0" value - Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am stuck,

we want to display value in H18 by adding cell(D18 & H17)

this is the formula I tried "=IF(ISBLANK(D18),0,(SUM(D18+H17)))"

once we are giving value in "D" Row then only we need to display value in H Row. including "zero"

"H" Row fully taking value as "0"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ranjit

```
=IF(D18="","",SUM(D18+H17))
```

This is working for me, give it a try.

Comment: Superb!! Worked well.. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

So, as per comment in view : show zero values - can be ticked or not...